# << operator overloading for template class object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, bitset

I have written a C++ STL like `bitset` class:

```
template<size_t N>
class bitset {
public:
 ...........
 friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &, bitset<N> const&);
private:
 ..........
};
// end of class

template<size_t N>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, bitset<N> const& rhs) {
    ............
    .........
    return os;
}
```

And I am trying to use it like this:

```
bitset<5> foo; // success
std::cout << foo << std::endl; // fail
```

And the error message is -

```
undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, bitSet<5u> const&)
```

What's the problem actually?

Comment: See here: [http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend's declaration must be a template as well, just like the definition is:

```
template <size_t N>
class bitset {
public:
    template <size_t M>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &, bitset<M> const&);
};

template <size_t M>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, bitset<M> const& rhs) {
    return os;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could declare the `operator<<` directly within the class scope:

```
template<size_t N>
class bitset {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & os, bitset const&) {
        return os;
    }
};
```

Comment: why don't you define the operator inside the class, so that's it is non-template at all?

Comment: @PiotrS. You should add that to your answer, it's IMO the best way of doing that.

Comment: @PiotrS what do you mean? please add to your answer if there are any better way

Comment: @MohitJain, Thanks for making a demonstration. I forgot that friend function can have also definition inside the friend class.

Comment: Note that with the template with `M`, all the `template operator << <M>` are friend with all `bitset<N>`.

Answer (score 3):

Some possible answers to your question are given [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html).

In addition to the answer of Piotr S., you can also predeclare the function templates:

```
template<size_t N> class bitset;
template<size_t N> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &, bitset<N> const&);

//now comes your class definition
```